# WebGL CPU vs GPU for transformations

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

I've recently begun toying with WebGL and I was wondering, for transformations (rotation, translation, scale, etc.) would it be faster to use JavaScript or a shader, or is it roughly the same?

Comment: Anything (with very few exceptions) that can be optimized by / done in hardware *will* be faster - and if there is a doubt, *benchmark* it. That being said, the question doesn't make much sense, because the two tasks presented are *not* strictly interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question:

> Is calculating the transformation matrix **for every vertex** of my
>   mesh on the gpu faster than calculating it **once** on the CPU.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but not being a professional developer, I thought it worth asking.